# Change color receipts label OS X Mail

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, email, plugins

I'm writing a plug-in for Apple OS X Mail in which I want to (based on some conditions) change the color of the label of an email-address in the e-mail compose window.

This (blue) label:

[image]

My plug-in is written in Swift (though, I could also work with an Obj-C solution).

I'm open for other suggestions as well, the main purpose is to notify the user of a certain "status" (green, orange, red) for a single email address.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? That's probably an NSTokenField/NSTextAttachmentCell.

Comment: I'm not sure in which class to find this attribute and how to modify it (it's the first time I'm developing a plug-in for Mail).

Comment: I would suggest [class-dump](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump) to try to find it, although it may be a completely default NSTokenField. Anyway, the drawing likely happens in some NSCell subclass (i.e. NSTextAttachmentCell). I believe Mail sometimes colors its tokens, so you might be able to find out how it's doing that and hook into the existing behavior.